# How to preview jasper report using java?

Tags: java, database, jasper-reports

i have created a report for my inventory control using IReport.then i found a code
to preview my report,this is that code,

```
package Report;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author Hasindu
 */
public class ReportView extends JFrame
{
    public ReportView(String fileName)
    {
        this(fileName, null);
    }
    public ReportView(String fileName, HashMap para)
    {
        super("ABC Solutions Employee/Project Management System (Report Viewer)");
        try {
            DB dba=new DB();
            Connection con=DB.getConnection();

            try
            {
                JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, para,con);
                JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
                Container c = getContentPane();
                c.add(viewer);
            }
            catch (JRException j){
                j.printStackTrace();

            }
            setBounds(10, 10, 900, 700);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

but my database connection code is returning a statement,this is my database connection code,

```
package Report;

import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DB {


public static Statement getConnection()throws Exception{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/report", "root", "123");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();

    return st;
}
```

}

Now i have two problems,

1. how to edit the report preview code to connect with my database connection code
2. i tested report preview code by creating this database connection code,

   ```
      public static Connection getCon()throws Exception{

           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/report", "root", "123");
       }
   ```

but when i run this code it's appears a empty window,
    please give a support

Comment: You can run/preview from iReport : http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/designing-report . You don't need an extra class for this.

Comment: thanks.i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly ,you are returning a `Statement` but it require `Connection` .don't create a `statement` create a `connection` to your db and return that `connection`  like following code example.

in `reportview` class

```
DB dba=new DB();
Connection con=DB.getCon();
```

`db.class`

```
package Report;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DB {

    public static Connection getCon() throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/report", "root", "123");
        return con;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm almost done with my application,so if i edit database class i have edit whole project,but i tested creating connection but report didn't appears.only empty window

Comment: @malindaweerasinghe you probably getting a error .if you declare return type as  `Connection`  your method should return a connection.i edited the code.actually don't chage your existing method create another method like `getCon()`  so this will not affect other codes

Comment: i mean no report but empty window

Comment: @malindaweerasinghe it's hard to guess what's wrong .you should look at your output window is there any error .may be your database has no records .did you add `getCon()` method as i told ? did you change `Connection con=DB.getConnection();` to `Connection con=DB.getCon();` ?? if you did can you show a snapshot ?

Comment: I am really sorry mate, there is a n error.i didn't check it before, there is a FileNotFound exception

Comment: @malindaweerasinghe then you should pass correct jasper file path to `ReportView()` constructor .check does that path exist

Comment: yes.but i generate the report using IReport netbeans plug in.

Comment: @malindaweerasinghe where is your jrxml file exist?you should pass it to the constructer .and can you add filenot found full error trace

Comment: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: report1.jasper
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:94)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:243)
 at Report.ReportView.<init>(ReportView.java:39)
 at Report.ReportView.<init>(ReportView.java:28)
 at Report.Report.jButton2ActionPerformed(Report.java:108)
 at Report.Report.access$100(Report.java:19)
 at Report.Report$2.actionPerformed(Report.java:50)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)

Comment: @malindaweerasinghe  you are creating new object of `ReportView` from somewhere .shaow  that line .it should be something like `new ReportView("xyz");`

Comment: yes. i passed "report1.jasper" and also "report1.jrxml".but same out put

Comment: @malindaweerasinghe not `report1.jasper` pass a full path for example 'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\report1.jasper'  and make sure this path is valid .in your error it's clear that you haven't pass valid file.first manually browse check is there your file exist or not